# What happens to a plug connection after it finishes the pipeline?

Tags: elixir, plug

I am currently looking into Phoenix and i am wondering what happens to a plug connection after it finishes its plug pipeline.

```
conn
|> endpoint
|> router
|> controller
|> view
```

The documentation says, that the `render/3` function will call the corresponding template function in the view and respond to the client with a status code of `200`. But what happens to the connection after this? Is the return used by any of the higher callers (for example the cowboy adapter), or does the pipeline simply finish with a open return that is unused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for `Plug.Conn.send_resp/1` at the time of writing](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/v1.3.5/lib/plug/conn.ex#L391-L396), you can see that the connection is first sent through the adapter, but it's then returned. This is because there can be other plugs that can get a connection with `state: :sent` and do arbitrary stuff with it and the information it contains. The final return value (see [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/2df667389dbaebb0e2102343c8d7a6ed4de6e280/lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex#L15)) is ultimately used by the adapter.

Comment: Do you have an example of a use case for a connection with `state: :sent`?

Comment: @LucaFülbier I never had to personally use it, and I can't think of anything useful off the top of my head, sorry :P